# Как вытащить значение data-src из img?

Tags: php

После парсинга одной страницы:

```
$d = $html->find('.thumb img[data-src]');
```

Получил это:

```
<img src="#" data-src="pic.png"  alt="something">
```

Как вытащить значение из `img` (`pic.png`)?

С помощью `explode` не хочется делать.

Comment: Используйте HTTP парсер типа [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Other отредактировал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы находите коллекцию, а не элемент.
Нужно либо перебрать её через цикл, либо взять первый элемент: `$html->find('.thumb img[data-src]', 0)`.
А там легко взять атрибут: `$d->{'data-src'}`.
Заметьте, `$d->data-src` не будет работать, т. к. выходит взятие поля и **минус**... константа?